# How to call parent class dynamically without mention the class name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm curious about how to call `one-level parent (not the oldest one)` of a class to get its `static` value and concat with current class static value. For instance:

```
class Grandpa {
  static xxx = [1,2]
}
class Father extends Grandpa {
  static xxx = [...Grandpa.xxx, 3] // how to get Grandpa's xxx value without mention Grandpa before .xxx?
}
class Child extends Father {
  static xxx = [...Father.xxx, 4] // how to get Father's xxx value without mention Father before .xxx?
}
console.log(Child.xxx) // [1,2,3,4]
```

How to do that?

Comment: Did you try `super.xxx`?

Comment: @jfriend00 it's a `static` property, can I call it with `super`?

Comment: Well, there is an example of that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).  I've never tried it myself.  You could write a 10 line test script to try it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#:~:text=Super-calling%20static%20methods

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super):

> The super keyword is used to access and call functions on an object's
> parent.
>
> You are also able to call super on static methods.

```js
class Grandpa {
  static xxx = [1,2]
}
class Father extends Grandpa {
  static xxx = [...super.xxx, 3] // how to get Grandpa's xxx value without mention Grandpa before .xxx?
}
class Child extends Father {
  static xxx = [...super.xxx, 4] // how to get Father's xxx value without mention Father before .xxx?
}
console.log(Child.xxx) // [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: It works. But can I also call `super.xxx` in a `non-static` method? Let's say if I have a method called `getXxx()` in `Child` class and I want to call `super.xxx` again inside it or I have to make it as `static` too?

Comment: Nope. super will work for non static as well. Read the link that I added for more information about super.

Comment: Then, will it not be ambiguous if a class has two methods (both `static` and `not`) with the same name and we want to call both of them with `super`?

Comment: Ok, so now I understand what you asked before. 
Why would you name two properties the same?
You can check out all these weird scenarios easily..I never tried to do something that bizarre ;)